# Covariance between two random variables

Tags: statistics, covariance, means

I am having trouble when it comes to a pair of random variables. Can you illustrate the procedure of how you think while solving problems like this? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will do the expectation part.

$$\mathbb{E}(U) = \mathbb{E}\left(Y - \alpha - \beta X\right)=\mathbb{E}(Y)-\alpha-\beta\mathbb{E}(X) \text{ ......why?}$$

Since

$$\alpha = \mu_Y - \beta \mu_X$$

We have

$$\mathbb{E}(U) = \mathbb{E}(Y) - \mu_Y + \beta\mu_X - \beta\mathbb{E}(X) \text{ ......why?}$$

Comment: Why does $E(\alpha)=\alpha$ in the first step? I understand the rest of it.

Comment: @J.doe That's a very good question. And why all of a sudden $\beta$ is by itself on the same line?

Comment: because they are parameters, not random variables?

Comment: @J.doe There you go

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I know the formula for the covariance $(X,Y)$ is $E(x-E(x))(y-E(y))$, but how to apply that to this question? Thanks!